# How to remove slo-mo tags from iOS videos using exiftool?

Tags: ios, photos

I have some slo-mo videos recorded that have been reverted back to normal speed. The problem is that the iOS Photos app still recognizes those videos as "slo-mo", and therefore places them in the "Slo-Mo" folder.

Similar to organizing burst photos in the "Bursts" folder, I can easily remove the **BurstUUID** using exiftool, which upon re-uploading the photo in the MAC Photos app, the photos are removed from the "Bursts" folder.

However, I don't see something similar to a "Slo-Mo" tag.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

There is no tag for slo-mo. Photo uses the frame rate (over 60fps) of the video to decide wether it is a slo-mo or not. GoPro videos with 120fps appear also in the slo-mo folder.

You have to convert the video to 60fps or less to achieve this, iMovie should work for this.

Comment: Maybe OP means album by slo mo

Comment: @ankii I’m not sure I understand your comment, the question *is* referring to the slow-mo album and this answer appears to be correct?

Comment: @grg I thought that despite having removed the slo-mo part by reducing that particular portion to zero time length, iPhone keeps it in slo mo album. My bad then, Please removed it all. :)